# How to use react-router

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I'm building a movie app that pulls data from `themoviedb` API. Right now, on the home page, I have a search form where I type the movie I want to look for. Then below, I display the result of the movies returned with a button that takes you to a page that displays more info about a particular movie.

My issue is with the routing. How do I do it in such a way that when I'm on the `movie-details` page, the `search` and `results` components are not displayed

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Route, Switch } from "react-router-dom";
import Navbar from "./navbar";
import Search from "./search";
import Result from "./result";
import Details from "./details";
import "./App.css";
import axios from "axios";

class App extends Component {
  state = {
    searchTerm: "",
    movies: []
  };

  onSearch = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.setState({ searchTerm: e.target.value });
  };

  handleSubmit = async e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const result = await axios.get(
      `https://api.themoviedb.org/3/search/movie?query=${this.state.searchTerm}&page=1&api_key=6f7ad5c4744feea1ee5508d2e56232c4`
    );
    this.setState({movies: result.data.results})
    console.log(result.data.results);
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="container">
        <Navbar />
        <Switch>
          {/* <Search handleSearch={this.onSearch} /> */}
          {/* <Route exact path="/" component={Search}  handleSearch={this.onSearch} handleSubmit={this.handleSubmit}/> */}
=          <Route
            exact
            path="/"
            render={props => (
              <Search
                {...props}
                handleSearch={this.onSearch}
                handleSubmit={this.handleSubmit}
              />
            )}
          />
          <Route path="/movie/" component={Details} />
          <Route path="/" component={Result} />
        </Switch>
        <Result movies={this.state.movies}/>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/github/peoray/movies-info

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `<Result />` component is outside of the router, so it's always being displayed. A quick fix here is to move it inside the router, like so:

```js
    return (
      <div className="container">
        <Navbar />
        <Switch>
          {/* <Search handleSearch={this.onSearch} /> */}
          {/* <Route exact path="/" component={Search}  handleSearch={this.onSearch} handleSubmit={this.handleSubmit}/> */}
          <Route
            exact
            path="/"
            render={props => (
              <>
                <Search
                  {...props}
                  handleSearch={this.onSearch}
                  handleSubmit={this.handleSubmit}
                />
                <Result movies={this.state.movies} />
             </>
            )}
          />
          <Route path="/movie/" component={MovieDetails} />
        </Switch>
      </div>
    );
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/todo-app-r38v5

Comment: Hey Nate. Thanks for the reply. It worked. But would you mind explaining the code to me especially the part you added the empty angle brackets and closed it after the `Result` component? Never seen something like that before

Comment: The empty tag is short for <React.Fragment>, allowing you to have multiple top-most elements without wrapping further HTML.

Comment: @Vladimir Thanks for the answer